# How to compute ROOK Polynomials for NxM Matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, permutations

How to compute ROOK Polynomials for NxM Matrices for k objects ?

Comment: Tuhin, the purpose of this site is not for asisting in homework. I'd say you may look at stackoverflow.com, but you already asked there (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071804/matrix-problem-in-c)

Comment: Also, "rook" shouldn't be capitalized.  It's a chess piece, not an abbreviation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answers of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20423/how-to-compute-the-rook-polynomial-of-a-ferrers-board).

Your case is a lot easier, just choose $k$ of the $m$ columns and then you have
$n (n-1)\ldots (n-k+1)$ ways to put the $k$ rooks. So the coefficient of $x^k$ is

$\displaystyle r_k = \binom{m}{k} n (n-1)\ldots (n-k+1) = \binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{k}k!$.

The provided link also gives a dynamic programming approach to compute $r_k$.